# getSharedPreferences() in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I have this code where I'll get all the available rows with same DueDateTime

```
public List<DatabaseSource> getListSched() {

    text = sharedPreference.getValue2(context);
    String shareFact = text.toString();
     List<DatabaseSource> schedList= new ArrayList<DatabaseSource>();
     // Select All Query

     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM schedTBL WHERE DueDateTime like " + shareFact;

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

     // looping through all rows and adding to list
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
             DatabaseSource sched= new DatabaseSource();
             sched.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
             sched.setSubject(cursor.getString(1));
             sched.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
             sched.setDueDateTime(cursor.getString(3));
             // Adding sched to list
             contactList.add(sched);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

     // return schedlist
     return schedList;
}
```

Am I doing it right??, it seems I cannot use the sharedpreferences in it, I have SharedPreferencesUID Class, I store this code below to get the value wherever I want to

`public String getValue2(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            String text;
            //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            text = settings.getString("dateselected", null);
            return text;
        }`

Comment: Can you share the code which is used to store the value

Comment: public void save(Context context, String text) {
         SharedPreferences settings;
         Editor editor;
         
         //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
         editor = settings.edit(); //2
  
         editor.putString("UID_Val", text); //3
  
         editor.commit(); //4
     }

Comment: As you mentioned,
While save you using "dateselected" this as key. But while retrieving you using  "UID_Val". Check that key. That key must me same

Comment: Sorry, It's wrong, this is the correct one preferences.edit().putString("dateselected", selectedGridDate).commit(); 
selectedGridDate is the date I got from the grid cell in the custom calendar

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could do is to MIGRATE getListSched to the activity where needs it (for specific activity only) then just call the DatabaseSched Class (which has the SQLiteOpenHelper) so I could use the sharedPreference.